# Yoast Seo Breadcrumbs Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo, breadcrumbs, yoast

Подскажите пожалуйста, может вы знаете где лежит файл с шаблоном вывода "Хлебных крошек" от Yoast Seo?
Там вообще такая проблема, что когда выводятся хлебные крошки, на каждый элемент открывается тег `<span>`, но не закрывает его. И если во фронте это не проблема(закрывает автоматически), то в бэке жалуется(жалуется валидатор кода).
И вот я пока не знаю, как мне правильно решить этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Предполагать, что такая нелепая ошибка существует в плагине с 5+ миллионов установок - плохая идея. Давно бы уже пользователи указали. Да и разработчики там высокого уровня, а плагин покрыт тестами. Тем не менее, давайте разберёмся.

Код вывода хлебных крошек содержится в файле `wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-breadcrumbs.php` (тесты этого класса есть на GitHub). Вывод каждого элемента - в функции `crumb_to_link()`. Из этих строк мы видим, что ошибки нет - ссылки оборачиваются в `span` или `strong`.

```
            $inner_elm = 'span';
            if ( $i === ( $this->crumb_count - 1 ) && WPSEO_Options::get( 'breadcrumbs-boldlast' ) === true ) {
                $inner_elm = 'strong';
            }

            $link_output .= '<' . $inner_elm . ' class="breadcrumb_last" aria-current="page">' . $link['text'] . '</' . $inner_elm . '>';
```

Но дальше по тексту видим

```
    return apply_filters( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', $link_output, $link );
```

И вот здесь-то ваша проблема. Где-то у вас в коде темы или других плагинов есть фильтр `'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link'`, который портит крошки, генерируемые Yoast.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Нашел, что ошибка возникает из-за функции удаления последней крошки. Но проблема в том что эта функция дается в пример везде. И как вы сами сказали, думать, что эту ошибку не заметили разрабы, нелепо. Наверное еще в чем-то может быть проблема, но я пока не нашел(((

Comment: Мало ли что даётся в примерах "везде". Ошибка не в коде Yoast, значит, мой ответ правильный.